# How to change screen resolution for 2.4" monitor via config.txt?

Tags: raspbian, display, pi-zero, screen, config.txt

I have tried changing the screen resolution of [my 2.4" monitor](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-2-4-pitft-hat-with-resistive-touchscreen-mini-kit) to 320x240, but no luck.

Here is my config.txt

http://pastebin.com/UdpHKLfP

I have no success changing the screen resolution. My monitor is connected via the GPIO pins, not the HDMI cable.

I have read somewhere that adding/uncommending these lines will help:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
```

But it hasn't, it's still the same resolution as it was before.

Here are screenshots how my screen looks like, as you can see, the resolution doesn't fit the screen size:

[image: PIXEL GUI screenshot]

[image: PIXEL GUI screenshot]

Comment: I don't own one of these, but I can't find anything anywhere that would suggest that that screen supports anything other than 320x240. What makes you suspect it's working at something else?

Comment: @goobering you don't understand. The resolution currently is not 320x240, it's something way higher, because a part of the screen is not visible. Probably 1024x768 as I checked the config file in the SD card and the default there was 1024x768. The problem is that I can't get the screen to become 320x240 resolution.

Comment: There are a few options on what the problem might be. Can you be a little more descriptive about what's being cut off in your display - are you only seeing a small section of what you should be seeing, is it cut off top/bottom/left/right, is it cut off in the PIXEL GUI interface or the command line interface or both...? If you can, a screenshot would probably be useful.

Comment: @goobering ok here are some screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/6BoAJ, as you can see, the resolution is way off for the screen size. The taskbar buttons are all melted together, and when I open any window only the top-left quarter of it is visible, the rest of it is not. Look at the libre office screenshot, only the menu buttons are visible.

Comment: The screenshots don't show a resolution issue. More of a scaling issue. You can check the actual resolution in a terminal session: `xrandr | grep "*"`